# PHP How can I create multiple sessions?

Tags: php, session

I want to be able to switch back and forth between sessions in php.  Here is my current code:

```
<?php

session_name("session1");
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "1";
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
session_write_close();

session_name("session2");
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "2";
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
session_write_close();

session_name("session1");
session_start();
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
```

I want it to output

```
Array
(
    [name] => 1
)
Array
(
    [name] => 2
)
Array
(
    [name] => 1
)
```

but it is outputting

```
Array
(
    [name] => 1
)
Array
(
    [name] => 2
)
Array
(
    [name] => 2
)
```

Is it possible to switch between sessions like that?  I don't need two sessions running at the same time, but I do need to be able to switch between them.  When I run this code, I get two cookies: session1 and session2 with the same value.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551404/php-what-is-the-purpose-of-session-name

Comment: Thanks, I already saw that.  That is exactly what I need, but for some reason it is not working.

Comment: Your title says it's "not working" when in fact it's not doing what you think it should do. Why not ask the appropriate question, *How can I do x? This is what I've tried.*

Comment: Using one `session_start();` only.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you mean leaving out session_write_close and only one session_start?

Comment: Use one of each only.

Comment: If you wish to switch, then use just that; `switch()` along with  conditional statements. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- It doesn't work, but I probably did something wrong.  So far I have one session_start in the first chunk along with a session_write_close, and a session_name in the second chunk, as well as the third.  For your second comment, could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Here's an answer on a similar (same?) question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/609818/451969 (or this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24131399/451969)) You might read through the whole question/answers/comments, especially the security ramifications.

Comment: @Nathan, It doesn't work because you have no if-statements. Otherwise, if you've tried with control logic, update the code in the question I guess.

Comment: Just as explained by `developerwjk` and in my comment. Plus, `switch()` allows you more control along with conditional statements.

Comment: @developerwjk Please elaborate.  How will if statements help this?  I am a php programmer but have never attempted to change sessions before. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you need to use is `session_id()` instead of `session_name()`

```
<?php

session_id("session1");
session_start();
echo session_id();
$_SESSION["name"] = "1";
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
session_write_close();

session_id("session2");
echo session_id();
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "2";
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
session_write_close();

session_id("session1");
echo session_id();
session_start();
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
session_write_close();

session_id("session2");
echo session_id();
session_start();
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
```

This will print:

```
session1

Array
(
    [name] => 1
)

session2

Array
(
    [name] => 2
)

session1

Array
(
    [name] => 1
)

session2

Array
(
    [name] => 2
)
```

`session_id` is an identifier for a session, which helps in distinguishing sessions. `session_name` is only a named alias for the current session

Comment: If you use this technique, different users with the same session ID will share their session variables. Session IDs are supposed to be unique and hard to guess.

Comment: The idea is that different users should not be provided the same session ID. Naturally it will not be a simple string like session1,sesson2 instead would be a uuid unique to that user or session.

Comment: This solution implies huge security risks unless well implemented.

Comment: This works for me, as mentioned in the reply, you need to keep a unique and secure session id.

Answer (score 9):

As the comments to the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965106/1711186) indicate, the offered solution might not be ideal and I would like to provide some alternative. Let it be a function named `sane_session_name()`, which looks like this:

```
function sane_session_name($name)
{
    session_name($name);
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$name]))
    {
        $_COOKIE[$name] = session_create_id();
    }
    session_id($_COOKIE[$name]);
}
```

By using the "sane" subsitution for `session_name()` in the OP's original code, we get this:

```
<?php
sane_session_name("session1");
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "1";
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
session_write_close();

sane_session_name("session2");
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "2";
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
session_write_close();

sane_session_name("session1");
session_start();
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
```

and it will yield the desired output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => 1
)

Array
(
    [name] => 2
)

Array
(
    [name] => 1
)
```

What is different?

To point out the difference between this answer and the [raidenace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965106/1711186):

- In [raidenace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965106/1711186) two sessions are created for all clients shared among all visitor of the website.
- With this answer two sessions are created for each visitor to the website. Consequently this would allow that in the `$_SESSION` superglobal different content can be stored for visitor Alice and Bob, while in the other two website visitor Alice an Bob would "share the data", and rather pointlessly a cookie named `PHPSESSID` with the value session2 is set each time and send back and forth.

**Security**

To protect those "multiple (per user) sessions" from *session fixation* and *session hijacking*, we can further use this litte function

```
function sane_session_start($name)
{
    ini_set("session.use_strict_mode",true);
    ini_set("session.cookie_httponly",true);
    session_name($name);
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$name]))
    {
        $_COOKIE[$name] = session_create_id();
    }
    session_id($_COOKIE[$name]);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_COOKIE[$name] = session_id();
}
```

and have the OP's code look like this:

```
<?php
sane_session_start("session1");
$_SESSION["name"] = "1";
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
session_write_close();

sane_session_start("session2");
$_SESSION["name"] = "2";
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
session_write_close();

sane_session_start("session1");
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, 1), "</pre>";
```

Comment: Simply awesome.