# Multiple session creation and assigning it to elements in php

Tags: php, session

I am able to create multiple sessions with my function but i am not able to assign to particular row where i am creating hyperlinks.

2.For example i have generated two rows with foreach loop

1. row1
   Data id1 name1  modify(edit basic data, add a file) /*  button with drop down
2. row 
   Data id2 name2  modify(edit basic data, add a file) /*
   my generated sessions are 
   ('id1.edit',id1.addfile1) and ('id2.edit',id1.addfile2)

Now I want to assign first set of session to first row and second set of session to second row. 
it means if i click on edit against id1 (row1) i should get 'id1.edit' as session and if i click on edit on row 2 i should get 'id2.edit' as my session

This switch case is used to generate links for items

```
if ($user -> isLoggedIn()) {
    $state = Input::get('state');
    switch ($state){
        case "draft":
        $leg_id = 0;
        $state_decode = 'Enquiries in Draft';
        $heading = 'Edit';
        $url = array('new_eis_form1.php','http://google.com','eis_equip_summary.php','enq_summary.php');
        $menu = array('Modify','Attach Files','Equipments','Lock');
        $btn = array('btn btn-info','btn btn-success','btn btn-info','btn btn-danger');
        $id_name = 'enq';
        break;
    case "submit":
        $leg_id = 1;
        $state_decode = 'Enquiries Submitted';
        $heading = 'View';
        $url = array('new_eis_form1.php','eis_equip_summary.php');
        $menu = array('Summary','Equipments');
        $btn = array('btn btn-info','btn btn-info');
        $id_name = 'enq';
        break;
    case "recvd":
        $leg_id = 2;
        $state_decode = 'Order Recieved';
        //$action = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';
        break;
    case "not_recvd":
        $leg_id = 3;
        $state_decode = 'Order Not Recieved';
        //$action = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';
        break;
    case "hold":
        $leg_id = 4;
        $state_decode = 'Enquireies Under Hold';
        //$action = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';
        break;
    case "wo1_pend":
        $leg_id = 2;
        $state_decode = 'Enquiries Pending for Wo-1';
        //$action = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';
        break;
    case "cancel":
        $leg_id = 7;
        $state_decode = 'Enquiries Cancelled';
        //$action = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';

    break;
    }
```

1. In the code below, I am creating dynamic links using two functions nav_items() and html().
2. each link will go to different page with some action
3. based on that action i want to get a session on the redirected page and perform action like add file/edit the data or add some more data on the item
4. But in this case i am not getting unique set of sessions but all of them available on all rows.

I want to get a set of sessions for first row ("edit01","attach01") and  ("edit02","attach02") for second row.

```
    if ($user -> isLoggedIn()) {
        $state = Input::get('state');
        switch ($state){
            case "draft":
            $leg_id = 0;
            $state_decode = 'Enquiries in Draft';
            $heading = 'Edit';
            $url = array('new_eis_form1.php','http://google.com','eis_equip_summary.php','enq_summary.php');
            $menu = array('Modify','Attach Files','Equipments','Lock');
            $btn = array('btn btn-info','btn btn-success','btn btn-info','btn btn-danger');
            $id_name = 'enq';
            break;
        case "submit":
            $leg_id = 1;
            $state_decode = 'Enquiries Submitted';
            $heading = 'View';
            $url = array('new_eis_form1.php','eis_equip_summary.php');
            $menu = array('Summary','Equipments');
            $btn = array('btn btn-info','btn btn-info');
            $id_name = 'enq';
            break;
        case "recvd":
            $leg_id = 2;
            $state_decode = 'Order Recieved';
            //$action = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';
            break;
        case "not_recvd":
            $leg_id = 3;
            $state_decode = 'Order Not Recieved';
            //$action = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';
            break;
        case "hold":
            $leg_id = 4;
            $state_decode = 'Enquireies Under Hold';
            //$action = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';
            break;
        case "wo1_pend":
            $leg_id = 2;
            $state_decode = 'Enquiries Pending for Wo-1';
            //$action = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';
            break;
        case "cancel":
            $leg_id = 7;
            $state_decode = 'Enquiries Cancelled';
            //$action = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';

        break;
        }
```

php:

```
<?php

function nav_items($menu=array(), $url=array(), $id_name,$param, $btn=array()){
    $str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= (count($menu)-1); $i++) {
    $str .= '<li>
                 <a href="' . $url[$i] . '?'.$id_name.'='.$param.'">'.oper($menu[$i],$btn[$i]).'</a>
             </li>';
    }
    return $str;
}
function html($heading,$menu, $url, $id_name,$param, $btn ) {
    $html = ' <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                        type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">'.$heading.'
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    ' . nav_items($menu, $url, $id_name,$param, $btn) . '
                </ul> ';

    return $html;           
}

function eis_session($heading,$menu,$param){
    foreach($menu as $menu_item){
        $eis_session = Session::put($menu_item, $heading.$menu_item.$param);
    }
    return $eis_session;
}

foreach ($data -> results() as $test) {
    $param = $test -> ENQ_NO;
    eis_session($heading,$menu,$param);
    echo "<tr>
<td>" . ++$slno . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-1\">" . $test -> ENQ_NO . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-1\">" . $test -> ENQ_DATE . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-3\">" . $test -> ENQ_DESR . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-1\">" . $test -> TENDER_REF_NO . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-2\">" . $test -> CUST_NAME . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-2\">" . $test -> PROJ_NAME . "</td>
<td class=\"col-md-1\">".html($heading,$menu, $url, $id_name,$test -> ENQ_NO, $btn)."</td>

</tr>";
    /* oper() function is in coomon.php; uses two inputs one is btn display label and oter is btn style class */
}

// }
?>
```

Comment: I have edited the post now. There is only problem code now

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP How can I create multiple sessions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964699/php-how-can-i-create-multiple-sessions)

Comment: Dear sagar the link does not solve my problem. I have explained it why.