# PHP 7.2 Warning: "Cannot change session name when session is active"

Tags: php, session, cookies, php-7.2

Since PHP on our server was upgraded to 7.2 from 7.0. I am getting the following warning (which leads to error) if a new deployment is done. The reason is probably, that old sessions get invalid after deployment.

> Warning: session_name(): **Cannot change session name when session is
>   active in** /var/www/html/model/login/lib/Session.class.php on line 137
>
> Warning: session_set_cookie_params(): **Cannot change session cookie
>   parameters when session is active in**
>   /var/www/html/model/login/lib/Session.class.php on line 138
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /var/www/html/model/login/lib/Session.class.php:137) in
>   /var/www/html/model/login/lib/Session.class.php on line 142

It seems like PHP 7.2 got more strict in the context of session sin a certain context. The server seems to recognize the invalid sessions and tries to destroy those. This is part of the Session class:

```
/**
 * Secure instant destruction of session. Must be called after session_start !
 */
public static function destroyAbsolute() {

    self::checkInit(); // unimportant

    session_name(self::$name); // this is line 137
    session_set_cookie_params(0, COOKIEPATH, null, self::$force_ssl_cookie, true);

    if(session_id()) {
        if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
            setcookie(session_name(), "", time() - 42000, COOKIEPATH);
        }
        unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

What has changed in PHP regarding sessions?

Why is it not allowed to set a session name if another session is active (*according to the docs with session_name I could change sessions and start multiple sessions*)?

And how may I destroy the running session appropriately?

Doing further research I also have found the following discussion on GitHub (https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2/issues/3185). **They confirm that this error was introduced with PHP 7.2**. Unfortunatly there is also no answer :-/

Comment: The `if(session_id()) {}` check suggests that `destroyAbsolute()` expects that some times `session_start()` has been called and some times it hasn't. Your call to `session_name()` should then follow the same logic.

Comment: The comment "Must be called after session_start" contradics the docs of `session_name()` "you need to call `session_name()` [...] before `session_start()`". I assume this code never deleted the session with the name `self::$name`.

Comment: @RolandStarke According to the docs session_name also can be set to SET or CHOOSE the name of the current session. Can you link to the docs as i can not find where this is documented?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php: "The session name is reset to the default value stored in session.name at request startup time. Thus, you need to call session_name() for every request (and before session_start() or session_register() are called)."

Comment: From which version was this upgraded from?

Comment: @Fred-ii- From 7.0. But it seems like the problem never has ocurred before.

Comment: TBH, I never installed 7 but PHP is basically "PHP", any which way you slice it. However, check to see if the upgrade made any modifications to the cookie/sessions settings. This could have something to do with included / required files, I'm guessing though. Possibly another service using it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just found a document which confirms that session handling has changed in PHP 7.2 (see edit). Still I am looking for a solution to this.

Comment: Well, least that's a step in the right direction. Did you have a look at the last comment in that page? The https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/7f196e3 - See also if anything comes of using error reporting and `var_dump()`'ing stuff, to see what's happening or not.

Comment: I thought session_name could be used for changing the current session name and manage multiple sessions? So it should be callable while a session is running in order to select another session or start a new session with the given name with session_start() afterwards. Should I report a PHP bug or did they just drop the concept of multiple sessions?

Comment: Using the [way back machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20010711032132/http://www.php.net:80/manual/en/function.session-name.php) and going as far back as possible (2001) you can find the same quote. "[...] before session_start() or session_register()". So i asume its not a new feature. maybe in previous versions it failed silent and now there is an error. Could you close the current session and start a new one? like `session_write_close(); session_name(self::$name); session_set_cookie_params(...); session_start();`?

Comment: I get this issue when upgrading to Drupal 7. Anyone else seeing this for Drupal can look [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3009351#comment-12938758).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have done a bug report at php.net and they explained that this is not a bug. *Yes in PHP 7.2 a warning is generated now.* However this never worked as intended, it **just failed silently**.

For creating multiple sessions it is required to use `session_id()`. Have a look at this related question: [PHP How can I create multiple sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964699/php-how-can-i-create-multiple-sessions)

`session_name()` as well as `session_set_cookie_params()` are always nonesense if the session is already running.

For the original answer have a look here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75650&thanks=2

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem but finally found a way through. The code below was my first approach that gave me errors.

```
static function startmysession($lifetime, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly){

    session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
    session_regenerate_id(true);

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }
}
```

Now Earlier versions of php overlooked our mistake(We were practically renaming and giving a session that already exists properties which is very wrong. So how did i solve this problem?

```
static function startmysession($lifetime, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly){      
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){  
         session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
         @session_regenerate_id(true);    
             session_start();
         }    
    }
```

I now bound the `session_set_cookie_params()` just before session start and I test if the session already exists before doing so.

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR:** if the session exists, use `setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), ...)` else use `session_set_cookie_params(...)`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#100657

> As PHP's Session Control does not handle session lifetimes correctly
>   when using session_set_cookie_params(), we need to do something in
>   order to change the session expiry time every time the user visits our
>   site. So, here's the problem.
>
> ```
> <?php
>   $lifetime=600;
>   session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
>   session_start();
> ?>
> ```
>
> This code doesn't change the lifetime of the session when the user
>   gets back at our site or refreshes the page. The session WILL expire
>   after $lifetime seconds, no matter how many times the user requests
>   the page. So we just overwrite the session cookie as follows:
>
> ```
> <?php
>   $lifetime=600;
>   session_start();
>   setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);
> ?>
> ```
>
> And now we have the same session cookie with the lifetime set to the
>   proper value.

My solution:

Originally:

```php
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();

        session_set_cookie_params(
            $seconds,
            $cookieParams['path'],
            $cookieParams['domain'],
            $cookieParams['secure']
            );
```

Now:

```php
        if(isset($_SESSION)) {
            if ($seconds != 0) {
                setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + $seconds);
            } else {
                setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), $seconds);
            }
        } else {
            $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();

            session_set_cookie_params(
                $seconds,
                $cookieParams['path'],
                $cookieParams['domain'],
                $cookieParams['secure']
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

hello where file modify the solution code

```
if(isset($_SESSION)) {
if ($seconds != 0) {
           setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + $seconds);
            } else {
                setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), $seconds);
            }
        } else {
            $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();

            session_set_cookie_params(
                $seconds,
                $cookieParams['path'],
                $cookieParams['domain'],
                $cookieParams['secure']
            );
        }
```