# PHP Warning: session_set_save_handler(): Cannot change save handler when session is active

Tags: php, yii, xdebug

My source Yii have this problem , when i use xdebug. I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: Where do you use this class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.2 Warning: "Cannot change session name when session is active"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700336/php-7-2-warning-cannot-change-session-name-when-session-is-active)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use Yii 1 with PHP 7.2
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47731428/10544072) and number of other sources like [this one](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/session-name-cannot-change-session-name-when-session-is-active/125598) and [this one](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/15318), you have a yii bug that can be reported [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii)

The answer from the other topic:

> I have done a bug report at php.net and they explained that this is
>   not a bug. Yes in PHP 7.2 a warning is generated now. However this
>   never worked as intended, it just failed silently.
>
> For creating multiple sessions it is required to use session_id().
>   Have a look at this related question: PHP How can I create multiple
>   sessions?
>
> session_name() as well as session_set_cookie_params() are always
>   nonesense if the session is already running.
>
> For the original answer have a look here:
>   https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75650&thanks=2

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix:

```
function _read($id)  
   PHP 7.0 -> if is empty return false
   PHP 7.2 -> if is empty return ''
```

*then add @ to other functions and remember to run session_name before session start*

```
@session_name('SOMEID');
@session_start(...
...
@session_set_save_handler(...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me:

1. Make new class `SomeSession` in `protected/components` folder:

```
class SomeSession extends CCacheHttpSession
{
    public function open()
    {
// don't start new session if session is started now
    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
    {
           parent::open();
    }
}
```

2. in `main.php` in `session` section edit:

```
'session'      => [
            'class'       => SomeSession::class,
            'sessionName' => 'SomeSessionName',
            'autoStart'   => true,
            'cookieMode'  => 'allow',
        ]
```

3. done =]