# session_cache_limiter error in symfony2.8 with php 7.2

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony-2.8, php-7.2

I am working on the project which is already build on Symfony. The versions and server details are as below

PHP: 7.2

Webserver: apache 2.4.6

Symfony: 2.8.1.1

I am getting below warning while initializing new session on my controller. This issue comes only when I am working on debugger mode(app_dev.php) not on production environment.

> "Warning: session_cache_limiter(): Cannot change cache limiter when
>   session is active"

I have gone through the issue over google and seen that it is core PHP warning.

How can we solve this with symfony 2.8 version?

Comment: See this link .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964699/php-how-can-i-create-multiple-sessions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems somewhere in the framework session_cache_limiter() is called after session_start(). It should be called before.

Comment: @NikhilJoshi hey, did you find finnaly solution to this bug?

Comment: @TomekKobyliński Not Yet.

Comment: @vrajeshDoshi, Thanks for insights, I have had tried this option. and we checked we were not setting the same anywhere. Though We have solved the issue.

Comment: @vrajesh I have added detailed Analysis This will help other to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

Who face this issue. Please do the below checks in the system. 
1. Check if anywhere in Yaml files have we set cache_limiter. The default have to be zero.

```
parameters:
    session.storage.options:
        cache_limiter: 0
```

2. In the flow also have a check if Session is getting set somewhere other than Autoload.

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

3. The most important is **DO NOT USE session_start** use Symfony's **session->start**.

In our application being legacy one It was found that at many places session_start was used. Thus as correctly said by @vrajesh session_start was being used.