# Login as another User, e.g. change session, switch user

Tags: php, apache

I have code which changes the current user session, its thought for an admin - to login as a existing user, and back again.

For that I store information in the session and in the DB. So Later I can check that the user trying to become admin, has the session variable - and in DB is the corresponding entry. So an attacker would have to set a session variable, and then also create a DB entry - from that point of view it seems safe to me.

User flow is:
The admin clicks a button, and that redirects him to a user frontend. Then in frontend is a button to get back to being admin.

Problem is I feel completely unsure about the following code, I am afraid having opened a security hole, or otherwise made a misstake. Overall this code is strange to me, working with PHP for years, but I never touched sessions.

Does this really properly create a new session?

```
//clear data in current session
foreach (array_keys($_SESSION) as $key) {
    unset($_SESSION[ $key ]);
}
//create new session id while old is active (takes care of collision)
$new_session_id = session_create_id();
//finish session
session_write_close();
//set new id
session_id($new_session_id);
//start with new id
session_start();
```

When switching to User following code gets executed after changing session:

```
 $_SESSION['mysessionkey'] = $admin_id;
//and more code making corresponding entry in db.
```

similar Question (but old answers and it does not help me - confuses me just more): [Can You Switch PHP Sessions In a Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609756/can-you-switch-php-sessions-in-a-session)

Comment: Facebook has just gotten hacked by doing basically what you described. Also, not sure it's a good idea for admins to login as other users, seems like a large point of failure.

Comment: Facebook has been hacked through a different security issue, yes "View as user", but ultimately something else, see https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/09/security-update/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not do that if i were you. This is to risky.

If you want to make a user switch use a laravel plugin(if you are using laravel).

if you are not using Laravel then you can make an api call for your users and with the api generator you can make a switch system to log you in as the user you want to login as with a new token.

JWT is a api i use to do that and my userswitch works fine.

GoodLuck

Comment: You mean I should not write my own Login mechanism, but instead use what is provided by the framework I use?
JWT is very interesting https://jwt.io/introduction/ thx for hint.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean it would save you much time and  you will be working with API's not sessions's

Comment: Well so far the code seems fine, I will soon write an answer myself to this. Yes this is problematic and impersonating a user comes with many caveats. But its a requirement, and I do not use Laravel, nor does the framework I use have such an API. JWT seems pretty amazing, something like that should be used instead of "traditional" php sessions in my opinion; but thats another topic for itself.

Comment: Yes Idd it is an another topic (a big one :P ). if you have built in your php api login system then you can add the user switch to it based on the pai key and not the session.